# How Do I Assign a Child Class a Specific Number for a Variable in Java?

Tags: java, class, parent-child

**Main Method**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW4 {

    public static int idScan() {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        int id = x.nextInt();
        return id;
    }
    
    public static double salaryScan() {
        Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
        double salary = y.nextInt();
        return salary;
    }
    
    public static int statusScan() {
        Scanner z = new Scanner(System.in);
        int status = z.nextInt();
        return status;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        Employee [] employee = new Employee[10];    
        employee [0] = new Employee(1, 0, 0);   
        employee [1] = new Employee(1, 0, 0);   
        employee [2] = new Employee(1, 0, 0);   
        employee [3] = new Employee(1, 0, 0);   
        employee [4] = new Employee(1, 0, 0);   
        employee [5] = new Employee(1, 0, 0);   
        employee [6] = new Employee(1, 0, 0);   
        employee [7] = new Employee(1, 0, 0);   
        employee [8] = new Employee(1, 0, 0);   
        employee [9] = new Employee(1, 0, 0);   
        
        for(Employee e : employee) {    
            System.out.println("Enter emplpoyee ID of an employee?");
            int id = idScan();
            System.out.println("Enter salary of the employee?");
            double sal = salaryScan();
            System.out.println("Is this employee a manager or worker? (Enter 1 for worker and 2 for manager)");
            int stat = statusScan();
        }

    }
}
```

**Employee.java**

```java
public class Employee {

    private int employeeID;
    private double salary;
    private int status;
    
    //Constructor
    public Employee(int ID, double esalary, int estat) {
        employeeID = ID;
        esalary = salary;
        status = estat;
    }
    
    //Getter ID
    public int getID() {
        return employeeID;
    }
    //Setter ID
    public void setID(int ID) {
        employeeID = ID;
    }
    
    //Getter Salary
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    //Setter Salary
    public void setSalary(double esalary) {
        salary = esalary;
    }
    
    //Getter Status
    public double getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    //Setter Status
    public void setStatus(int estat) {
        status = estat;
    }
}
```

**ManagerEmployee.java**

```java
public class ManagerEmployee extends Employee {

    //Super Constructor
    public ManagerEmployee(int ID, double esalary, int estat) {
        super(ID, esalary, estat = 1);
    }   
}
```

**WorkerEmployee.java**

```java
public class WorkerEmployee extends Employee {

    //Super Constructor
    public WorkerEmployee(int ID, double esalary, int estat) {
        super(ID, esalary, estat = 2);
    }
}
```

The program I'm doing involves calculating paycheck for employees via scanner input with two types of employees (Manager/Worker). One part that I'm torn up over involves the part where I need to input a number to indicate a worker or manager (1 for worker and 2 for a manager) via the scanner in the for loop. I'm generally confused on where I need to establish that rule whether it's in the Employee class or the two child classes.

Comment: Use the _instanceof_ keyword.  _if (employee[i] instanceof Worker)_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I Verify Scanner Inputs with a .txt File And Create A New .txt File That Takes Those Inputs And Format Them Into a Printed Statement (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77519959/how-do-i-verify-scanner-inputs-with-a-txt-file-and-create-a-new-txt-file-that)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to implement a factory pattern. In that case, you can make the `Employee` class `abstract`. Because there will be no `Employee` who is just an `Employee`. It has to be either a `Manager` or a `Worker`. As you are using polymorphism, you don't need to keep the `status` in the `Employee` class. You can find what type of employee it is by its type. So, your class hierarchy becomes

**Employee.java**

```
public abstract class Employee {

    private int employeeID;
    private double salary;

    //Constructor
    public Employee(int ID, double esalary) {
        employeeID = ID;
        salary = esalary;
    }

    //Getter ID
    public int getID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    //Setter ID
    public void setID(int ID) {
        employeeID = ID;
    }

    //Getter Salary
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    //Setter Salary
    public void setSalary(double esalary) {
        salary = esalary;
    }
}
```

**ManagerEmployee.java**

```java
public class ManagerEmployee extends Employee {

    //Super Constructor
    public ManagerEmployee(int ID, double esalary) {
        super(ID, esalary);
    }

}
```

**WorkerEmployee.java**

```java
public class WorkerEmployee extends Employee {

    //Super Constructor
    public WorkerEmployee(int ID, double esalary) {
        super(ID, esalary);
    }

}
```

In the main method, you should create the specific employee after checking the user input.

**HW4.java**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW4 {

    public static int idScan() {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        int id = x.nextInt();
        return id;
    }

    public static double salaryScan() {
        Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
        double salary = y.nextInt();
        return salary;
    }

    public static int statusScan() {
        Scanner z = new Scanner(System.in);
        int status = z.nextInt();
        return status;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numOfEmployees = 10;
        Employee[] employee = new Employee[numOfEmployees];

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfEmployees; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter employee ID of an employee?");
            int id = idScan();
            System.out.println("Enter salary of the employee?");
            double sal = salaryScan();
            System.out.println("Is this employee a manager or worker? (Enter 1 for worker and 2 for manager)");
            int stat = statusScan();
            if (stat == 1) {
                employee[i] = new WorkerEmployee(id, sal);
            } else if (stat == 2) {
                employee[i] = new ManagerEmployee(id, sal);
            } else {
                // handle error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Alternatively**, we can use `enum` and get rid of the child classes as they do not add any properties/functionalities to the `Employee` class. In that case

**Employee.java**

```java
public class Employee {
    public enum Status {
        MANAGER,
        WORKER
    }

    private int employeeID;
    private double salary;

    private Status status;

    //Constructor
    public Employee(int ID, double esalary, Status stat) {
        employeeID = ID;
        salary = esalary;
        status = stat;
    }

    //Getter ID
    public int getID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    //Setter ID
    public void setID(int ID) {
        employeeID = ID;
    }

    //Getter Salary
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    //Setter Salary
    public void setSalary(double esalary) {
        salary = esalary;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

And your `main` method would become

```java
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numOfEmployees = 10;
        Employee[] employee = new Employee[numOfEmployees];

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfEmployees; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter employee ID of an employee?");
            int id = idScan();
            System.out.println("Enter salary of the employee?");
            double sal = salaryScan();
            System.out.println("Is this employee a manager or worker? (Enter 1 for worker and 2 for manager)");
            int stat = statusScan();
            if (stat == 1) {
                employee[i] = new Employee(id, sal, Employee.Status.WORKER);
            } else if (stat == 2) {
                employee[i] = new Employee(id, sal, Employee.Status.MANAGER);
            } else {
                // handle error
            }
        }
    }
```

It is similar to your current approach, but `enum` is used in place of `int` so that any arbitrary value can not be assigned as `status`.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I'm generally confused on where I need to establish that rule whether it's in the Employee class or the two child classes. ..."*

Create either a *Worker* or *Manager* class, depending on whether *stat* is *1* or *2*.

```java
abstract class Employee {
    int employeeID;
    double salary;
    int status;

    Employee(int employeeID, double salary, int status) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.status = status;
    }
}

class Manager extends Employee {
    Manager(int employeeID, double salary, int status) {
        super(employeeID, salary, status);
    }
}

class Worker extends Employee {
    Worker(int employeeID, double salary, int status) {
        super(employeeID, salary, status);
    }
}

class HW4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Employee [] employee = new Employee[10];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0, n = employee.length; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter emplpoyee ID of an employee?");
            int id = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter salary of the employee?");
            double sal = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Is this employee a manager or worker? (Enter 1 for worker and 2 for manager)");
            int stat = in.nextInt();
            if (stat == 1) employee[i] = new Worker(id, sal, stat);
            else employee[i] = new Manager(id, sal, stat);
        }

    }
}
```